# SharedPreferences not working across Activities

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save some filters/state in one activity, and then use that data in the next activity.

I'm using SharedPreferences, but it isn't working as I'd expected it to.

```
public class FilterActivity extends Activity {

  private static final String TAG = FilterActivity.class.getName();

  EditText distanceEditor;

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PreferenceKey.FILTER_PREFERENCES_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String distance = distanceEditor.getText().toString();
    preferences.edit().putString(PreferenceKey.DISTANCE, distance);
    preferences.edit().commit();
    Log.i(TAG, "Wrote max-distance=" + distance);

    Log.i(TAG, "Preferences contains distance=" + preferences.getString(PreferenceKey.DISTANCE, "FAIL"));
  }


  public static class PreferenceKey {
    public static final String FILTER_PREFERENCES_NAME = "FilterActivity:" + "Filter_Preference_File";
    public static final String DISTANCE = "FilterActivity:" + "DISTANCE";
  }
}
```

Then, the Activity that should use this preference:

```
public class MapActivity  extends MapActivity {
  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(FilterActivity.PreferenceKey.FILTER_PREFERENCES_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String maxDistance = preferences.getString(FilterActivity.PreferenceKey.DISTANCE, "FAIL");

    Log.i(TAG, "Read max-distance=" + maxDistance);
  }
}
```

But the output I get is:

```
.FilterActivity( 4847): Wrote max-distance=99.9
.FilterActivity( 4847): Preferences contains distance=FAIL
.MapActivity( 4847): Read max-distance=FAIL
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I am developing against API Level-8.

Comment: Is it because in your second activity your asking for RestaurantFilterActivity.PreferenceKey.DISTANCE but in the first activity you save it under FilterActivity.PreferenceKey.DISTANCE ? or is that a typo :-)

Comment: Your log output actually shows it's not getting saved to start with. Have you checked Double.toString(distance); isn't null?

Comment: Typo, and fixed in the question now, sorry.

Comment: Do you need other applications to read your preferences? I would just 0 or MODE_PRIVATE, for the preferences mode.  p.s. you need .show() after the Toast to view it.

Comment: I would also move the super.onPause() to the bottom of the Activity method. As you want your activity specific code to run before the application starts cleaning it up for Pause.

Comment: @Brundell: I set the MODE to public, as it wasn't working in MODE_PRIVATE, and was hoping that the public mode might fix it : it didn't! I'll switch back to MODE_PRIVATE once it's working for me. Also, I removed the Toast from the question now, as it's not relavent, but thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the following two lines,

```
preferences.edit().putString(PreferenceKey.DISTANCE, distance);
preferences.edit().commit();
```

two different `SharedPreferences.Editor`s are being returned. Hence the value is not being committed. Instead, you have to use:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = preferences.edit();
spe.putString(PreferenceKey.DISTANCE, distance);
spe.commit();
```

Comment: That's fixed it!
Thank you. The examples I saw did indeed use the pattern you suggest, but didn't realise that it was a requirement. 
Silly me.
Thank you!

Comment: You can also use a oneliner: `preferences.edit().putString(PreferenceKey.DISTANCE, distance).commit();`