# In App Purchases Not Saving Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, android-activity, in-app-purchase, sharedpreferences

I have an android application similar to wheel of fortune where users have the option to purchase one consumable, $1000, and two entitlements, where they unlock two images as wheel styles. I am using the Amazon In-App Purchasing API. The user should be able to purchase as many consumables as they want but once they purchase the entitlements the unlocked image should be the only image that they see and they should no longer see the locked image. These in-app purchases work fine the first instance I initiate these purchases.
However, the consumable field will only update once and even though I can still go through the process of completing purchases for the consumable, the text view containing the score, or money, does not update other then that first initial purchase. Also the wheels return to the locked image rather then remaining as the unlocked image despite the fact that when I initiate the purchase for these entitlements I am told that I already own these items. Therefore I believe it may be something to do with my SharedPreferences. In short my purchases update my views once and then never again, however the backend code i.e the responses I receive from the Amazon client when completing purchases are correct. Can anyone see where I have made a mistake? Why does the textView containing the score update on the 1st purchase and never again from then on? Also how do I save the changes toe the wheel style so that when it reopens they no longer have the option to purchase the wheel? I have three classes and have included the code below. All and any help is greatly appreciated.

Game Class

```
public class Game extends Activity {

private ImageView wheel;
private int rand;
private int[] amounts = {100,650,-1,650,300,-1,800,250,-1,500};
private int score = 0;
private TextView scoreText;
private AnimatorSet set;
protected boolean animationDone = true;
private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefsChanged);

    wheel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

    score = prefs.getInt("score", 0);       
    scoreText.setText("$" + String.valueOf(score));
}

private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefsChanged = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
            String key) {
        if(key.equals("money") && prefs.getBoolean(key, false)) {
            score += 1000;
            scoreText.setText("$" + String.valueOf(score));
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("money", false);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    InAppObserver obs = new InAppObserver(this);
    PurchasingManager.registerObserver(obs);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(this.isFinishing())
    {
        prefs.edit().putInt("score", score).commit();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    prefs.edit().putInt("score", score).commit();       
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        String style = data.getStringExtra("wheel");
        if(style.equals("camo"))
            wheel.setImageResource(R.drawable.camowheel);
        if(style.equals("gold"))
            wheel.setImageResource(R.drawable.goldwheel);
        if(style.equals("normal"))
            wheel.setImageResource(R.drawable.wheel);
    }
}

public void spinTheWheel(View v) {
    if(animationDone) {
        wheel.setRotation(0);
        rand = (int) Math.round(2000 + Math.random()*360);
        set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(wheel, View.ROTATION, rand));
        set.setDuration(2000);
        set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        set.start();
        animationDone = false;
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                calculateResult();
                animationDone = true;
            }
        });
    }       
}

private void calculateResult() {
    int angle = (int) wheel.getRotation();
    angle %= 360;
    angle = (int) Math.floor(angle/36);
    if(amounts[angle] == -1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
        intent.putExtra("score", score);
        prefs.edit().putInt("score", 0).commit();
        score = 0;
        startActivity(intent);
    }   
    else {
        score += amounts[angle];
        scoreText.setText("$"+String.valueOf(score));
        prefs.edit().putInt("score", 0).commit();
    }       
}

public void upgradeWheel(View v) {      
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChangeWheel.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

public void endGame(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameOver.class);
    intent.putExtra("score", score);
    prefs.edit().putInt("score", 0).commit();
    score = 0;
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void addMoney(View v) {
    PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseRequest("money");
}
}
```

ChangeWheel Class

```
    public class ChangeWheel extends Activity {

private Button buyCamoButton;
private Button buyGoldButton;
private ImageButton goldButton;
private ImageButton camoButton;
private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_wheel);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefsChanged);

    buyCamoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyCamo);
    buyGoldButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyGold);
    goldButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.goldButton);
    camoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camoButton);
    goldButton.setEnabled(false);
    camoButton.setEnabled(false);
}

private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefsChanged = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
            String key) {
        if(key.equals("camo") && prefs.getBoolean(key, false)) {
            camoButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.camowheel);
            camoButton.setEnabled(true);
            buyCamoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if(key.equals("gold") && prefs.getBoolean(key, false)) {
            goldButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.goldwheel);
            goldButton.setEnabled(true);
            buyGoldButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    InAppObserver obs = new InAppObserver(this);
    PurchasingManager.registerObserver(obs);
}

public void camoClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Game.class);
    intent.putExtra("wheel", "camo");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}

public void goldClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Game.class);
    intent.putExtra("wheel", "gold");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}

public void normalClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Game.class);
    intent.putExtra("wheel", "normal");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}

public void buyCamo(View v) {
    String req = PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseRequest("camo");
    prefs.edit().putString(req, "camo").commit();
}

public void buyGold(View v) {
    String req = PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseRequest("gold");
    prefs.edit().putString(req, "gold").commit();
}
}
```

InAppObserver Class

```
public class InAppObserver extends BasePurchasingObserver {

private SharedPreferences prefs;

public InAppObserver(Activity caller) {
    super(caller);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(caller.getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public void onSdkAvailable(boolean isSandboxMode) {
    PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest(Offset.BEGINNING);
}

@Override
public void onPurchaseUpdatesResponse(PurchaseUpdatesResponse res) {
    for(String sku : res.getRevokedSkus()) {
        prefs.edit().putBoolean(sku, false).commit();
    }
    switch (res.getPurchaseUpdatesRequestStatus()) {
    case SUCCESSFUL:
        for(Receipt rec : res.getReceipts()) {
            prefs.edit().putBoolean(rec.getSku(), true).commit();
        }
        break;
    case FAILED:
        // do something
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPurchaseResponse(PurchaseResponse res) {
    switch(res.getPurchaseRequestStatus()) {
    case SUCCESSFUL:
        String sku = res.getReceipt().getSku();
        prefs.edit().putBoolean(sku, true).commit();
        break;
    case ALREADY_ENTITLED:
        String req = res.getRequestId();
        prefs.edit().putBoolean(prefs.getString(req, null), true).commit();
        break;
    case FAILED:
        // do something
        break;
    case INVALID_SKU:
        // do something
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are not using the same editor.

```
preferences.edit().putString(PreferenceKey.DISTANCE, distance);
preferences.edit().commit();
```

> two different SharedPreferences.Editors are being returned.  Hence the
>   value is not being committed. Instead, you have to use:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = preferences.edit();
spe.putString(PreferenceKey.DISTANCE, distance);
spe.commit();
```

From... [SharedPreferences not working across Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442190/sharedpreferences-not-working-across-activities)